# Copy and Paste String (Persian, Arabic) in PHPStorm is Wrong

Tags: string, utf-8, phpstorm, arabic, persian

Copy and Paste String (Persian, Arabic) in PHPStorm is Wrong

**my string is:** به نام خداوند بخشنده مهربان

**Describe In image:**

[image: Text when pasted]

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Persian,Arabic is a RTL language right? PhpStorm (as well as other IDEs on IDEA platform) does snot have proper support for editing RTL languages. I do not think it can be resolved from your end unfortunately. Check this ticket for details: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5810

Comment: With set `editor.new.rendering=true`  in in the file `bin/idea.properties` in Php storm 10 problem solved

Comment: Go to this page and submit your issue for helping their developers to fix the problem.

https://youtrack-support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/1651

Answer (score 20):

In the install directory, in the file `bin/idea.properties`, add **one** of the following:

- `editor.new.rendering=true` 
  Use the new rendering engine which has rtl support. This is default since PhpStorm 2016.1.
- `editor.disable.rtl=true` 
  This is only a workaround: characters will simply appear left-to-right instead.

Comment: The new rendering engine solution solved my problem in PS 10, thank you very much!

Comment: The new rendering engine option works great in WebStorm 11.0
شكرا

Comment: 2021 here, and I need to figure this out for WebStorm please... where do I find the install directory for MacOS? It's not in Library/ApplicationSupport/JetBrains...